# Asp Net Identity Token Issue with ELB

Tags: identity, amazon-elb

We have configured the ELB with 2 server for the Web API.  Updated the MachineKey in both the server to be same.

When the Reset Token password/Confirm password  is created  from server1. The Url is sent to the User Email when the Verify token call is Made the Server1 Verify the token successfuly, But if call is sent to the Server 2, Server 2 always returns Invalid Token. Do i  need  to make any configuration chanages other than the Machine Key.

Comment: Please include some code

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the all the request belongs to one session goes to the single backend. 
In order to do this enable session stickiness on the ELB. This will make sure that request always gets routed to the same backend.

On Classic Load balancer : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-sticky-sessions.html

On Application Load Balancer : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-target-groups.html#sticky-sessions